# Spark SQL Split with Period (.)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I encountered a problem in spark 2.2 while using pyspark sql, I tried to split a column with period (.) and it did not behave well even after providing escape chars:

```
>>> spark.sql("select split('a.aaa','.')").show()
+---------------+
|split(a.aaa, .)|
+---------------+
|   [, , , , , ]|
+---------------+

>>> spark.sql("select split('a.aaa','\\.')").show()
+---------------+
|split(a.aaa, .)|
+---------------+
|   [, , , , , ]|
+---------------+

>>> spark.sql("select split('a.aaa','[.]')").show()
+-----------------+
|split(a.aaa, [.])|
+-----------------+
|         [a, aaa]|
+-----------------+
```

It uses period only when we provide it like [.] while it should also be working with escape seq '\.'. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: I think in the end you should just use `[.]` and not try to escape it with slashes. Most of the time you have to escape it multiple times and it is a mess.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like you need to escape the `\\`:

```
spark.sql("""select split('a.aa', '\\\\.')""").show()
```

If you were to run it directly in SparkSQL it would just be

```
select split('a.aa', '\\.')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @swdev commented above you can just do this:

```
spark.sql("select SPLIT(value,'[.]') from demo").show
```